# issue centering activity indicator

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, subview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am having an issue centering an activity indicator view inside a subview, and I am not sure why. It is loading correctly, just not sure why it is not centered in the subview...thanks in advance!

controlsContainerView.frame = frame
        addSubview(controlsContainerView)

```
    controlsContainerView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Where do you call this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`centerXAnchor` is a property of a view. It isn't clear what the view is in the `equalTo` part of your code:

```
activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

Try to explicitly naming the view:

```
activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor)
.isActive = true
```

Comment: I figured it out...forgot to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false.  thanks